# Line Chart of Recharts showing tooltip at wrong place with wrong coordinates. I hover at some place but it shows data of other coordinates

Tags: reactjs, tooltip, linechart, recharts

I am using recharts to implement line graphs in my project but the tooltip behaves abnormally. Lets say i need the data on the tooltip for the coordinate x1,y1 and when i hover over x1,y1 the tooltip does not show up at all but when i hover over x2,y2 the tooltip shows up and it shows the data of x1,y1.
Similarly when i hover over x3,y3 the data for x2,y2 shows up. And when i hover over x4,y4 which is also the last coordinate, nothing gets showed up including the tooltip.

```js
<div style={{"display":"flex"}}>
                        <div style={{"flexBasis":"25%"}}>
                        <LineChart
                            width={300}
                            height={170}
                            data={data1}
                            margin={{
                                top: 15,
                                right: 20,
                                left: 20,
                                bottom: 0
                              }}
                            //   onMouseMove={(state) => {
                            //     if (state.isTooltipActive) {
                            //       setFocusBar(state.activeTooltipIndex);
                            //     } else {
                            //       setFocusBar(null);
                            //     }
                            //  }}
                            >
                                        {/* <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" /> */}
                                        <XAxis dataKey="name" allowDuplicatedCategory={false} style={{"fontFamily":"Mars Centra","fontSize":"12px"}}/>
                                        <YAxis type="number" domain={[0, 200]} tickCount={4} hide={true}/>
                                        {/* <Tooltip content={<CustomTooltip/>}/> */}
                                        <Tooltip active={true} wrapperStyle={{visibility:"visible"}} content={<CustomTooltip/>}/>
                                        <Legend />
                                        <text
                                        x='50%'
                                        y='50%'
                                        dy={-70}
                                        style={{ fontFamily: 'Mars Centra', fill: '#575757' }}
                                        width={200}
                                        scaleToFit={true}
                                        textAnchor='end'
                                        verticalAnchor='end'
                                    >
                                        Investment
                                    </text>
                                        <Line
                                            type="monotone"
                                            dataKey="value"
                                            stroke="#8884d8"
                                            activeDot={{ r: 8 }}
                                            isAnimationActive={false}
                                        />
                                        </LineChart>
                        </div>
```

```js
const CustomTooltip = ({active,payload,label} => {
.....
})
```

This is the javascript code that i have written. When i hover over x1,y1, on putting a debugger inside this customtooltip function i see that the active and payload are been passed as false and an empty array respectively.. I do not understand why is this happening.
Any help/lead is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you reproduce  the issue using a codesandbox snippet? I mean I am currently working on Recharts and didn't yet face this issue